# MissingParameter when calling the DeleteSnapshot operation

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I want to look for the snapshot created last week and delete it automatically by using this code :

```
last_week = today - timedelta(days=7)
logger.info('Looking for snapshots of : {0}'.format(str(last_week)))
tag_value_last = 'snap-hebdo-'+str(last_week)
all_snaps = ec2client.describe_snapshots( Filters=[ {'Name': 'tag-value','Values': [tag_value_last]}],)
if all_snaps == None:
    logger.error('No snapshot found with the tag : {0}'.format(tag_value_last))
    sys.exit(1)
else:
    snapshotId_last =''
    for i in all_snaps['Snapshots']:
        snapshotId_last = i['SnapshotId']
    logger.info('Old snapshot of {0} found with ID: {1}'.format(str(last_week),snapshotId_last))
    logger.info('Deleting the snapshot with ID : {0} ...'.format(snapshotId_last))
    ec2client.delete_snapshot(SnapshotId=snapshotId_last)
    logger.info('Done.')
```

My problem is that the logger gets the message `Old snapshot of 2017-01-16 found with ID:` 
and ̀ Deleting the snapshot with ID :  ...` then I get the error

```
An error occurred (MissingParameter) when calling the DeleteSnapshot operation: The request must contain the parameter id
```

What I don't understand why the script enters the else of the condition even that the variable all_snaps is empty and it does not return any snapshot ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `describe_snapshots()` does not return `None`  when there is no match for the filters. The response here would look like `{'Snapshots': []}`.

You should modify the `if` with checking the length of list under `Snapshots` key in the response dict.

```
if not len(all_snaps['Snapshots']):
    sys.exit(1)
```